# how to count elements with specific atribute from to different series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i need to calculate the percentage of athletes that have participate on summer and winter olimpic games, from the athlete_events.csv.

i already try to asign values to each athletes, but i continue got on an infinite loop. 
the data displays like this:

```
Name    Sex Age Height  Weight  Team    NOC Games   Year    Season  City    Sport   Event   Medal
A Dijiang   M   24  180 80  China   CHN 1992 Summer 1992    Summer  Barcelona   Basketball  Basketball Men's Basketball NA
```

Have no actual error messeges, just an infinite loop

```
   df= pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Rorro\Desktop\desafio latam\athlete_events.csv")
   pjt = df.loc[:,"Name"]
   pjt = pjt.drop_duplicates()

   temp = df.loc[:,["Name","Season"]]
   total = 0
   for i in pjt:
      for l,r in temp.iterrows():
        if i == r["Name"] and r["Season"] == "Winter":
          for n,m in temp.iterrows():
            if i == m["Name"] and m["Season"] == "Summer":
                total+=1
            else:
                pass
        elif i == r["Name"] and r["Season"] == "Summer":
          for n,m in temp.iterrows():
            if i == m["Name"] and m["Season"] == "Winter":
                total+=1
            else:
                pass
        else:
           continue
```

print(total)

Comment: Hi, I think you should have a look at the `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`. If you still need help, after that, please add some test data records and the expected output.

Comment: hey! ty for the help. The problem is that i need to count just one time each athlete that paticipate in both sesons. The CSV have just the name and the season for each year.
The expected output would be a number X ≤ (total number of athletes)

Comment: Hi, if one athlete participates in both, where does he count then? the summer or the winter games?

Comment: Thats the problem, each row have the name, year and season of the athlete, he/she can even participate in different season from differen years, so in my code i just include the name and the season, triying to count every time that the name is the same, first for the winter season, and then into the loop again to find if the name have a Summer season and then count +1 to the total

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Season': ['winter', 'summer', 'winter', 'summer'],
                   'Name'  : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'],
                   'Year'  : [1992, 1996, 2004, 2000]})
print(df)

# Defines the wanted seasons
selection = (df['Season'] == 'summer') | (df['Season'] == 'winter')

# Defines the wanted years    
selection = selection & (df['Year'].isin([1992, 1996, 2000]))

names = df[selection]['Name']
print(names)

unique_count = len(names.unique())
print("\nDistinc itens: {}".format(unique_count))
```

Prints:

```
   Season Name  Year  
0  winter    a  1992  
1  summer    b  1996  
2  winter    c  2004  
3  summer    a  2000  

0    a  
1    b  
3    a  
Name: Name, dtype: object  

Distinc itens: 2
```